# Как убрать подписи элементов BottomNavigationView android?

Tags: android

У меня есть такая менюшка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_shop"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_shop"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_gifts"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

и есть такой тулбар внизу экрана:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

я не могу понять как убрать надписи под элементами тулбара, вроде поставил `app:showAsAction="never"` но это никак не помогло, пробовал другие параметры ставить - тоже не помогло. Я хочу что-бы у меня там были просто иконки, а у меня сейчас такой экран получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-то знает в чем может быть проблема. Буду очень благодарен если поможете убрать эти подписи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574662/7566397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В item уберите у каждого

```
android:title=""
```

Если у вас стоит Android Support Library 28.0.0-alpha1, то там есть

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
```

Comment: вроде-бы такие элементы не могут без title жить нормально? или могут?

Comment: Ну проверьте, если не будет работать, то сделайте так android:title=""

Comment: нет так не работает)) я еще перед тем как вопрос задать пробовал)) и Ваш второй вариант я тоже пробовал, он конечно работает, но иконка все-равно выше среднего уровня, а мне нужно что-бы иконки висели четко по центру toolbar.